# Is it safe to use a Temporary or Virtual Number for creating whatsapp account?

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger, data-monitoring

This article in link below mentions some web links and apps that can be used to generate temporary or virtual number, for creating whatsapp account

I want to know, whether this whole process is safe/secure or there any major apparent risks in this process?Such as collecting data from android phone(especially from confidential apps like banking apps) on which theses apps/links are opened for creating temporary or virtual phone number ?

https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/whatsapp/how-to-use-whatsapp-without-phone-number.html

Comment: As far as I know who ever controls the phone number can take-over your WA account and get access to your active chats. Therefore I would say no it is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

Since WhatsApp uses OTP authentication using your mobile number for login purposes , using one of those temporary number to create an account is not recommended if you want that account to be permanantly with you.